# ¿Cómo enviar texto de un DropDownList al controlador?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lo que quiero es enviar el valor seleccionado de la sucursal al método de búsqueda que he creado en el controlador, ya que desea buscar vendedores según la sucursal seleccionada en el `DropDownList`. Pero quiero enviar el parámetro de la sucursal seleccionada para que lo reciba el método y lo procese para hacer las consultas adecuadas.

¿Cómo puedo enviar el valor seleccionado (el texto no id) de mi `DropDownList` al método de mi controlador?

Aquí el código de mi controlador deseo recibir el valor seleccionado.

```
public ActionResult Filtro(string suc="")
{
    List<Vendedor> ls = db.Vendedor.ToList();
    var  tl = 0;
    if(suc.Length > 0)
    {
        ls = db.Vendedor.Where(a => a.Sucursal.Nombre == suc ).ToList();
        tl = ls.Count();
    }

    ViewBag.tl = tl;
    return View(ls);

}
```

Aquí la vista donde tengo el DropDownList del cual deseo enviar el valor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Vendedor", new {},FormMethod.Get))
{
  <div>
  @Html.DropDownList("SucursalId",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Sc, "", new { @class = "form-control" })

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que decis que lo filtre por id de la sucursal, pero se me ha pedido que lo filtre por el nombre de la sucursal por ello desea enviar el texto seleccionado que contiene el dropdownlist, espero explicarme.

Comment: Asi es amigo exactamente, y que al presionar boton buscar me aparescan los vendedores registrados en esa sucursal.

Comment: Ok lo intentare gracias por la ayuda..

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas :
La primera es Mandar el Id de la sucursal y  posteriormente en el método buscas la sucursal y la encontrada comparas el nombre con el de los vendedores

La vista donde tienes tu DropDownList

```
@html.DropDownList("SucursalId",ViewBag.Sc as SelectList,"--Seleccione uno--",new{@class="form-control"})
```

Metodo donde recibes el valor :

```
Public ActionResult Filtro(int SucursalId)

{
var sucursal  = db.sucursal.Find(SucursalId);
ls = db.Vendedor.Where(a=>a.Sucursal.Nombre==sucursal.Nombre).Tol‌​ist(); 
Return View(ls);
}
```

*La segunda forma es :*

en el metodo donde envias los datos al DropDownList

```
ViewBag.Sucursales = new SelectList(db.Sucursal,"Nombre","Nombre");
```

y en la vista para poder recibirlos :

```
@html.DropDownList("SucursalNombre",ViewBag.Sucursales as SelectList,"--Seleccione uno--",new{@class="form-control"})
```

y por ultimo en el método donde recibes el nombre de la sucursal para comparar

```
public ActionResult Filtro(string SucursalNombre)
{
    ls = db.Vendedor.Where(a=>a.Sucursal.Nombre==SucursalNombre).Tol‌​ist(); 
    Return View(ls);
}
```